# nmcli add a route to dev not a next hop

Tags: rhel, route, nmcli, interface

Need to add a static route with nmcli to a device interface.
I would like to mimic a command like this with ip route (traffic sent to the interface NOT a next-hop ip)

```
ip route add 4.4.0.0/30 dev ens4
```

I already know how to use to add a next hop interface but I cant find any documentation on how to send a route to a specific interface

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you mean `nmcli connection modify ens4 +ipv4.routes ip/30 [next_hop]`

Comment: Not if "next_hop" is an interface IP, already know how to do that. I need a specific command to send traffic to "dev ens4". Not sure what the syntax would be in nmcli as with the syntax you shared an edit is done directly to an interface.

Comment: I’m not an expert on this, but I believe that, if you want 4.4.0.0/30 IP traffic to flow through `ens4`, then you need to give `ens4` an address in that range — i.e., 4.4.0.1 or 4.4.0.2. Perhaps I’m misunderstanding what you want to accomplish.  Can you explain a bit? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I think `nmcli connection modify ens4 +ipv4.routes "4.4.0.0/30"`.
I usually do it like that.